# Two styled Google maps on single page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd appreciate some help setting up two Google maps (API 3) on a single page. They've got some shared styles. I can get a single one running, but not two together.

- http://theredfrog.com/new/temp3.html - one map (ok)
- http://theredfrog.com/new/temp4.html - two maps (broken)

Here's the script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
var styles = [
  ....

];

var hulloptions = {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
    },

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.7413176, -0.3353987),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: 'StyledHull'
};

var leedsoptions = {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
    },

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.796177,-1.541862),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: 'StyledLeeds'
};

maphull = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-hull"),hulloptions);
mapleeds = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-leeds"),leedsoptions);

var image = './skin/logo.png';
var HullLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.7413176, -0.3353987);
var LeedsLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.796177,-1.541862);

var rfdMarkerHull = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: HullLatLng,
      map: maphull,
      icon: image
  });
  var rfdMarkerLeeds = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: LeedsLatLng,
      map: leedshull,
      icon: image
  });

var styledMapTypeHull = new google.maps.StyledMapTypeHull(styles, { name: 'RFD Hull' });
var styledMapTypeLeeds = new google.maps.StyledMapTypeLeeds(styles, { name: 'RFD Leeds' });
maphull.mapTypes.set('StyledHull', styledMapTypeHull);
mapleeds.mapTypes.set('StyledLeeds', styledMapTypeLeeds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags aren't keywords.  Combining `google`, `maps` and `api` doesn't mean you're talking about the Google Maps API for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines don't look right:

```
var styledMapTypeHull = new google.maps.StyledMapTypeHull(styles, { name: 'RFD Hull' });
var styledMapTypeLeeds = new google.maps.StyledMapTypeLeeds(styles, { name: 'RFD Leeds' });
```

Don't you get an error in the JavaScript console on those?

I think you meant:

```
var styledMapTypeHull = new google.maps.StyledMapType( styles, {
    name: 'RFD Hull'
});
var styledMapTypeLeeds = new google.maps.StyledMapType( styles, {
    name: 'RFD Leeds'
});
```

(also reformatted slightly for shorter lines)

Here's some [more information and a working example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype).

And now that I try your second map in with the Developer Tools open in Chrome, I see there are other errors before it even gets that far.

First a warning:

```
Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times
on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

Then `lazyload` is undefined here in `plugins.js`:

```
$(".lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectspeed: 600,
    failure_limit: 10
});
```

And then a mysterious-looking error inside some Maps API compressed code, but if you look at the call stack, you'll see your `initialize` function in the stack, and if you click on that it goes to this line:

```
mapleeds = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-leeds"),leedsoptions);
```

Paste this into the JavaScript console and you'll see what's wrong:

```
document.getElementById("map-leeds")
```

And more errors after that, before even getting to the problem I saw while looking at your code.

So you have some debugging to do. Are you familiar with the Developer Tools in Chrome or another browser? If not, now it is time! Here is a [great introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are (you need to run through your code with a debugger):

1. typos (`map: mapleeds,` not `map: leedshull,`
2. ordering, you can't use variables before you initialize them
3. these are not valid:  `google.maps.StyledMapTypeHull`, `google.maps.StyledMapTypeLeeds` (maybe a search and replace gone wrong.  Should be `google.maps.StyledMapType`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var maphull = null;
   var mapleeds = null;
   function initialize() {
   var styles = [
   {
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -100 }
      ]   
    },{
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'all',
   stylers: [
          { lightness: -74 },
          { visibility: 'on' }
         ]
    },{
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
       { lightness: -26 },
       { visibility: 'simplified' }
      ]
   },{
   featureType: 'road',
   elementType: 'geometry',
   stylers: [
       { hue: '#efefef' },
       { lightness: 83 },
       { visibility: 'simplified' }
      ]
   },{
         featureType: 'poi',
         elementType: 'all',
           stylers: [
         { hue: '#999999' },
             { saturation: -100 },
             { lightness: -23 },
             { visibility: 'on' }
          ]
   },{
       featureType: 'road',
       elementType: 'labels',
           stylers: [
            { saturation: -100 },
            { visibility: 'on' }
      ]
     }
   ];

   var hulloptions = {
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
      },

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.7413176, -0.3353987),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: 'StyledHull'
    };

    var leedsoptions = {
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
           mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
       },

       center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.796177,-1.541862),
       zoom: 15,
       mapTypeId: 'StyledLeeds'
     };

   var image = './skin/logo.png';
   var HullLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.7413176, -0.3353987);
   var LeedsLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.796177,-1.541862);

   var styledMapTypeHull = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'RFD Hull' });
   var styledMapTypeLeeds = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'RFD Leeds' });

   maphull = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-hull"),hulloptions);
   mapleeds = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-leeds"),leedsoptions);

   maphull.mapTypes.set('StyledHull', styledMapTypeHull);
   mapleeds.mapTypes.set('StyledLeeds', styledMapTypeLeeds);
     var rfdMarkerHull = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: HullLatLng,
        map: maphull,
        icon: image
     });
     var rfdMarkerLeeds = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: LeedsLatLng,
         map: mapleeds,
         icon: image
     });
   }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
   ```