# How to create two google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to know how to embed two different google maps with info windows for two companies.
[this is sample one, i want two different maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) .
I want two different maps.
Not two info windows in the same map.

Thanks.

Comment: try using javascript to write some code

Comment: related question: [Two styled Google maps on single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881693/two-styled-google-maps-on-single-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

Put two divs in your html instead of one:

```
...
<div id="map1"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
...
```

Then add the javascript code to create both maps:

```
  function initMap(mapName, lat, lng, title, content) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapName), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: lat, lng: lng}
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title: title
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }

var contentUrulu = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
var
    contentWhatever = '...';

  initMap('map1', -25.363, 131.044, 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)', contentUrulu);
  initMap('map2', 46.106,7.049, 'Whatever', contentWhatever);
```